# AndroidStudio - Module Already Disposed

Tags: android, android-studio, module

I know this has been asked and other solutions have been approved, but none of those are working for me.
I've tried everything from the other SO threads....deleting modules.xml and .iml files, clearing caches, etc...i cant even remember or list all of the things ive tried. ive updated to the latest AS version Dolphin... nothing is working

Heres the best part, even brand new empty projects are getting this error. How is this possible? What is any possible solution:

Brand new, empty project. How is this happening?

```
com.intellij.serviceContainer.AlreadyDisposedException: Already disposed: Module: 'My_Application' (disposed)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.checkState(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:184)
        at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:533)
        at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ModuleRootManager.getInstance(ModuleRootManager.java:37)
        at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.RootIndex.buildRootInfo(RootIndex.java:182)
        at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.RootIndex.<init>(RootIndex.java:72)
        at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.RootIndex.<init>(RootIndex.java:56)
        at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.DirectoryIndexImpl.getRootIndex(DirectoryIndexImpl.java:172)
        at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.DirectoryIndexImpl.getRootIndex(DirectoryIndexImpl.java:155)
        at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.DirectoryIndexImpl.getInfoForFile(DirectoryIndexImpl.java:182)
        at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.FileIndexBase.getInfoForFileOrDirectory(FileIndexBase.java:96)
        at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectFileIndexImpl.getInfoForFileOrDirectory(ProjectFileIndexImpl.java:27)
        at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectFileIndexImpl.isUnderIgnored(ProjectFileIndexImpl.java:87)
        at com.intellij.history.integration.IdeaGateway.isVersioned(IdeaGateway.java:85)
        at com.intellij.history.integration.IdeaGateway.isVersioned(IdeaGateway.java:51)
        at com.intellij.history.integration.IdeaGateway.areContentChangesVersioned(IdeaGateway.java:169)
        at com.intellij.history.integration.LocalHistoryEventDispatcher.beforeContentsChange(LocalHistoryEventDispatcher.java:101)
        at com.intellij.history.integration.LocalHistoryEventDispatcher.handleBeforeEvent(LocalHistoryEventDispatcher.java:111)
        at com.intellij.history.integration.LocalHistoryEventDispatcher.lambda$handleBeforeEvents$0(LocalHistoryEventDispatcher.java:174)
        at com.intellij.history.integration.IdeaGateway.runWithVfsEventsDispatchContext(IdeaGateway.java:147)
        at com.intellij.history.integration.LocalHistoryEventDispatcher.handleBeforeEvents(LocalHistoryEventDispatcher.java:172)
        at com.intellij.history.integration.LocalHistoryEventDispatcher$LocalHistoryBulkFileListener.before(LocalHistoryEventDispatcher.java:245)
        at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.invokeMethod(MessageBusImpl.java:645)
        at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.invokeListener(MessageBusImpl.java:620)
        at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBusImpl.java:417)
        at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpWaitingBuses(MessageBusImpl.java:390)
        at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:372)
        at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.access$200(MessageBusImpl.java:33)
        at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$MessagePublisher.invoke(MessageBusImpl.java:179)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy200.before(Unknown Source)
        at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.fireBeforeEvents(PersistentFSImpl.java:1181)
        at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.applyMultipleEvents(PersistentFSImpl.java:1148)
        at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.processEventsImpl(PersistentFSImpl.java:1130)
        at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.AsyncEventSupport.processEventsFromRefresh(AsyncEventSupport.java:150)
        at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshSessionImpl.fireEventsInWriteAction(RefreshSessionImpl.java:226)
        at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshSessionImpl.lambda$fireEvents$1(RefreshSessionImpl.java:205)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$runEdtProgressWriteAction$11(ApplicationImpl.java:911)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:188)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$12(CoreProgressManager.java:624)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:646)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:623)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:175)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.PotemkinProgress.runInSwingThread(PotemkinProgress.java:164)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$runEdtProgressWriteAction$12(ApplicationImpl.java:911)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteActionWithClass(ApplicationImpl.java:935)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runEdtProgressWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:909)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteActionWithNonCancellableProgressInDispatchThread(ApplicationImpl.java:890)
        at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshSessionImpl.lambda$fireEvents$2(RefreshSessionImpl.java:199)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteAction.lambda$run$1(WriteAction.java:86)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteActionWithClass(ApplicationImpl.java:935)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:961)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteAction.run(WriteAction.java:85)
        at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshSessionImpl.fireEvents(RefreshSessionImpl.java:198)
        at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshQueueImpl.lambda$runAsyncListeners$9(RefreshQueueImpl.java:148)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.NonBlockingReadActionImpl$Submission.lambda$safeTransferToEdt$6(NonBlockingReadActionImpl.java:577)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:214)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$200(TransactionGuardImpl.java:21)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:196)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:805)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$invokeLater$4(ApplicationImpl.java:348)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:82)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:131)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:47)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue$FlushNow.run(FlushQueue.java:187)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:891)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:760)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:447)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:818)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:446)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:805)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:492)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Im so sick of this error and there being no suggested solutions from Google/Android.
I've had this error in the past and have been able to apply the other solutions to resolve it, but this time nothing is working and im sick of it.